# How to write a cloud-init script to download and run a program?

Tags: amazon-ec2, upstart, cloud-init

I have Go compiled executable (say on S3) that I'd like to download and run (perpetually) on a set of EC2 instances (an auto scaling group). This needs to be completely automatic via cloud-init.

The closest I can find is to use `upstart` and do something like this

```
#upstart-job
description "APP1"

start on cloud-config
console output
service

script
curl http://server.com/app
app -p 9090
end script
```

Is this really that simple? And will this make upstart manage the application as a service as well?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Cloudformation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) for automated installations? Check this out here: [Automating Application Installation Using AWS CloudFormation and Cloud-Init](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-waitcondition-article.html)

Or are you looking for entirely something else?

Comment: No, this is really interesting. I've always assumed Cloudformation only dealt with AWS level assets, never with applications themselves. Will check it out.

Comment: Cool. Good luck with that, Sudhir. :)

Comment: Just checked - this is fine for a simple start, but I'd need the app to be monitored - it needs to be restarted even if it goes down. The usual technique here is upstart, so I'm trying to figure out a way to download the app create the upstart job.